# How to remove high frequency regions from a canny image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Assume I have a canny detected image, for example this one I stole from the internet:

[image]

I need to detect and remove regions with high frequency features. So this image should become soemthing like:
[image]

(Excuse the GIMP skills)

In other words, areas containing high variability of of features should just go to black.

To my understanding I could use something like fourier transforms to filter out these kinds of regions, but I am not sure how or if this is the best approach.

Comment: "To my understanding I could use something like fourier transforms to filter out these kinds of regions, but I am not sure how or if this is the best approach." yes, indeed that is an approach. The better way to do it is to do a low-pass filter *first*, and *then* detect edges. What's nice about this is that a low-pass filter is analogous to a Gaussian blur---you don't even need to do a Fourier transform manually. Simply blurring the image before detecting the edges will reduce a lot of spurious high frequency edges. Of course, to get more fine-grained, one would go into Fourier space.

Comment: The thing is, I need to work directly on the edge detected image, I cannot modify the original image prior to getting the binary edge mask

Comment: Oof. Ok, that is a bigger problem, as--like I said, removing the high frequencies from an image (for e.g. via a low-pass filter) is analogous to blurring. So if you just do that to your edge image, you're going to simply blur the edges and nothing else really. You'll need a different approach than just filtering.

Comment: Well, you can mathematically define those regions, they are regions where there is a lot of variability from white to black. 

I know that, manually, I could just create a convolution filter that measures the variability within that window and sets things to white or black based on a treshold.
but this would be really slow.

Comment: Right, but that's in the spatial domain. Edges themselves are high frequency features, so it's not really helpful to do frequency domain analysis for this problem. At least, not that I know of. What about a box filter? That will take the average over some window---if there's a lot of edges, then there will be more white and thus a higher average. Thresholding a box filter might give you a mask of places to remove.

Comment: That could work, I need to try it out

Comment: So, did you try the above? How did it work out?

Comment: I have not been able too yet. This is related to my work and I got a sudden pile of work thrown onto me that I need to finnish before pursuing these kinds of experiemnts

Comment: worked reasonably well for me. thanks @alkasm